# Mapping to and from model in the same controller's action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

let's say I have a post method in my MVC app which is doing some kind of search (from DB, files, whatever):

```
 public IActionResult Index (SomeViewModel viewModel)
 {
     var model = mapper.map<SomeViewModel,SomeModel>(viewModel);
     var searchResultModel = DoSearch(model);
     var searchResultViewModel = mapper.map<SearchResultModel,SearchResultViewModel>(searchResultModel);
     return RedirectToAction("SearchResult",searchResultViewModel);
 }
```

Is such kind of mapping, back and forth from model/viewmodel considered bad practice?
If yes, how can I improve similar functionality?

Comment: Why do you use view model instead of model?Could you share more details?

Comment: @Rena, I am using both. ViewModel is entity I am using when I am interfering with my view. Then I map it to my model, which is used by my business layer. Then I map this the other way to view model and show this view model through view to user